# console.log не печатает данные

Tags: javascript

```
var james = {
    job: "programmer",
    married: false,
    sayJob: function() {
        // complete this method
        console.log("Hi, I work as a " + this.job);
    }
};

// james' first job
james.sayJob();

// change james' job to "super programmer" here
james.job = "super programmer";

// james' second job
james.sayJob();
```

По какой-то причине я не вижу, что `console.log()` печатает данные. Это один из уроков на codecademy, и встроенный интерпретатор ничего не показывает. Проверил на другом сайте - тоже ничего. Кто-нибудь знает, в чем дело?

[image: скрин 1]
[image: скрин 2]

Comment: добавьте картинку, на которой видно, что не печатает

Comment: В том, что консоль у Вас закрыта?

Comment: @in43sh  Вы не туда смотрите... консоль надо у браузера открыть

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, у подобных сервисов вывод в консоль так же дублируется на специальное окно/вкладку

Comment: всем большое спасибо! я все понял!

Comment: А у меня кстати работает http://s020.radikal.ru/i709/1512/72/d3c5d319259e.jpg

Comment: @in43sh ты все понял. а на самом деле не все так просто))

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский то есть?)

Comment: @in43sh ну открыть консоль браузера - это не совсем то. Как написал @Grundy  -  у некоторых сервисов вывод в консоль дублируется в окно. Вот мой скрин сверху показывает что ваш код в `codeacademy` работает...... а в  другом редакторе написано что чтоб вывести данные надо использовать `write` и `writeln` то есть это уже ваша ошибка и недосмотр

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский так в итоге, что вы советуете использовать для печати данных?

Comment: @in43sh в вашем случае может был какой-либо кратковременный глюк у кодакадемии. Попробуйте там еще раз `console.log` в любом уроке. Должно работать. Если не работает, то можно открыть консоль браузера и посмотреть что там происходит, может там ошибки какие-то сыпятся. В этом случае может представителям школы (codeacademy) показать что у них что-то сломалось. Но я думаю это было что-то кратковременно

Answer (score 1):

Ваш код абсолютно работоспособен. Проверяйте так:

Сохраните его в текстовый файл с расширением `.html`, обрамив тегом `<script>`:

```
<script>
  // Ваш код...
</script>
```

Откройте консоль браузера (для Firefox: Настройки - Разработка - Веб-консоль)

Откройте в браузере сохранённый файл.

PROFIT

Вероятно, действительно у codeacademy глюки.